# GoREST endpoint path

Tags: go, endpoint, gorest

I'm writting a web service with Go and I'd like to have url like :

http://example.com/WEB/service.wfs?param1=2&param2=test.....

I'm using GoREST and my Endpoint url is :

```
method:"GET" path:"/WEB/service.wfs?{param:string}" output:"string"
```

My problem is that it never return the "param" but it does if I use the endpoint :

```
method:"GET" path:"/WEB/service.wfs/{param:string}" output:"string"
```

Is there a way to handle the "?" ?

Comment: A short google search yielded at least 3 different projects called "gorest", which one are you using?

Comment: Sorry ! I use this one : https://code.google.com/p/gorest/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in gorest though it's not as nice as gorest's preferred mechanism.

Don't include your query parameters in your endpoint definition

```
method:"GET" path:"/WEB/service.wfs" output:"string"
```

Instead, you can get at the context from your registered end point and get the query parameters using something like

```
func (serv MyService) HelloWorld() (result string) {
    r := serv.Context.Request()
    u, _ := url.Parse(r.URL.String())
    q := u.Query()
    result = "Buono estente " + q["hi"][0]
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at the GoREST package you are using and can not see any way of doing this.

I have always used gorillatoolkit pat package.

[gorillatoolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/pat)

There is an example of what you want to do about half way down.

```
category := req.URL.Query().Get(":category")
```

This way you can get the query parameters on the request URL by the key.

Hope this helps.